# Combining nunique and where in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find, for every id: the number of values equal to 0.0 and greater than 0.0

Input DF:

```
ID .   value
1 .     0.0
1 .    10.0
1 .    30.0
1 .     0.0
1 .     25.0 
2 .     0.0
2 .     4.0
2 .     0.0
2 .     13.0
```

Output DF:

```
id .    count (value = 0.0) .   count(value > 0.0)
1             2                      3
2 .           2                      2
```

Code:

```
df.groupby("ID")["value"].nunique()
```

which just returns the number of unique values for each ID, I am not sure how to combine this if-else of (0.0 and value>0.0) in that command. Any suggestions please

Comment: The output DF is your desired end state?

Comment: @Kyle yes M trying to create a DF exactly like the op

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with

```
pd.crosstab(df.ID,df.value.gt(0))
Out[392]: 
value  False  True 
ID                 
1          2      3
2          2      2
```

Comment: And if you wanted the column names: `pd.crosstab(df.ID, np.where(df.value.gt(0), 'value > 0', 'value == 0'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['equal'] = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: sum(x==0))
df['greater'] = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: sum(x>0))
```